# 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'explore'

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I wanted to try Geopanda's interactive visualization, and the function `.explore()` unfortunatly I have this error message : `'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'explore'` Which is quite weird as `GeoDataFrame` should be compatible with `explore` (https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html). I'm using Geopandas v. 0.9.0. and my code is :

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://docker:docker@127.0.0.1:25432/mobilitydb')
query=gpd.read_postgis("Select traja,mmsia from filtered where nm_a is not null and geometrytype(traja)='LINESTRING'",engine,geom_col='traja')
plot=query.explore()
```

does anyone as an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is with the version of Geopandas you are using. I had a similar issue. I had originally installed geopandas from the apt repository(I am using Kali Linux). I uninstalled geopandas, and then installed it using `pip3 install geopandas folium matplotlib mapclassify`. That seemed to work for me. The version pip installed was geopandas-0.10.1

Comment: I followed your advices but the install failed because of "fiona", I even tried to do it in a new environment and I had the same issue

Comment: I finally managed to upgrade to Geopandas 0.10.0 with a WinPython distribution. I wasn't able to it with Anaconda, and it works.

Comment: For anyone running into this in 2022 and using conda, conda-forge has the latest versions of geopandas (default channel tops out at 0.9 still)

Answer (score 2):

Try to update your geopandas package (either using conda or pip )
you can use this command :

```
pip install geopandas==0.10.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to output all attributes of your objects.
Use: `print(dir(query))` and `print(dir(gpd))`
There is `explore()` inside?

Comment: There is no explore() in both cases